# I cannot enter the value for type2 or grind2 or wght2 in the output what is the error?

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    
    char type1, grind1, cream1;
    int wght1;
    double temp1;

    char type2, grind2, cream2;
    int wght2;
    double temp2;


    printf("COFFEE-1...\n");
    printf("Type ([L]ight,[B]lend): ");
    scanf("%c", &type1);
    printf("Grind size ([C]ourse,[F]ine): ");
    scanf(" %c", &grind1);
    printf("Bag weight (g): ");
    scanf(" %d", &wght1);
    printf("Best served with cream ([Y]es, [N]o): ");
    scanf(" %c", &cream1);
    printf("Ideal serving temperature (Celcius): ");
    scanf(" %.1lf", &temp1);
    printf("\n");

    printf("COFFEE-2...\n");
    printf("Type ([l]ight,[B]lend): ");
    scanf(" %c", &type2);
    printf("Grind size ([C]ourse,[F]ine): ");
    scanf(" %c", &grind2);
    printf("Bag weight (g): ");
    scanf(" %d", &wght2);
    printf("Best served with cream ([Y]es,[N]o): ");
    scanf(" %c", &cream2);
    printf("Ideal serving temperature (Celcius): ");
    scanf(" %.1lf", &temp2);
    printf("\n");


    return(0);
}
```

i can enter the value for type1,grind1,wght1,cream1 and temp1
but not for the 2nd time ........
I'm new to coding and my assignment is due tomorrow
welp T_T

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier `%.1lf` is not correct.

Unlike `printf` format specifiers, `scanf` format specifiers don't take a precision, so remove it.

```
scanf(" %lf", &temp1);
...
scanf(" %lf", &temp2);
```

Answer (score -2):

Please clear keyboard buffer use fflush(stdin).
After temp1 input please type in next line

fflush(stdin)

Then next statements  as it is...